# SSL certificate on server change

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, https

I had purchased a SSL certificate from Godaddy for my server. Now I changed my server and copied the key and csr files over to new server but they are being perceived as self signed.

Do I need to recreate the certificate and sign it again on new server?

Answer (score 1):

Just found the answer here. The certificate needs to be re-Keyed

http://community.godaddy.com/help/867/what-does-it-mean-to-rekey-a-certificate